# How to find MySQL 8.0 user and password on Docker + WSL2

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-for-windows

I followed the instructions as shown on the Laravel website:

[Getting Started On Windows](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-windows)

And now I have a running container with a few images, one of them is the MySQL 8.0.
But I can't log in to MySQL using `"root@localhost"` without password. So I assume some random password was generated. How can I find it? Or if it's impossible, how to properly delete and reinstall a new image of MySQL (Not mysql-server)

If I have to  reinstall MySQL please explain to me how to do it and make the newly re-installed image show under the Laravel project container, and not separately

Thanks

Comment: No; It most definitely is not a random password it's one that the user assigns.  That tutorial has no actual instructions, It's not clear, what instructions you used so you knew what commands to run.

Comment: Thank you. I found out where they installed it. You're right. It's not clear and annoying...

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

If any other beginner will encounter the same problem:
the Sail installation installs a default username and password that you can find in the `.env` file at`/home/username/project-name/.env`